# NodeJS: is their anyway to emulate the window global var defined in browser?

Tags: node.js

Is their anyway in NodeJS to emulate the **window** var defined in browser ?

Comment: Define emulate. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: i mean when i run my script i have : This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK :(

Answer (score 0):

The `window` variable is dedicated for browers only.
I'm not sure what you need, but you can define a "global" object on NodeJS, for example : define an object, export it somewhere and include it as "window" on every file/module you're working in.